# Генерация строки по регулярному выражению

Tags: javascript, typescript

Можно ли как-то сгенерировать строку (каждый раз должна возвращаться случайная строка) используя регулярное выражение?
Делаю через получение рандомного символа из заданной строки, но думаю можно сделать по-лучше

```
    static getRandmonString(stringLength: number): string {
    let text = '';
    const possible =
        'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz 0123456789+-)(;.,:%№"! абвгдеёжзийклмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьэюяАБВГДЕЁЖЗИЙКЛМНОПРСТУФХЦЧШЩЪЫЬЭЮЯ';
    for (let i = 0; i < stringLength; i++) {
        text += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));
    }
    return text;
}
```

Comment: Регулярные выражения нужны для поиска и сопоставления строк указанным шаблонам, с генерацией они не помогут :)

Comment: Можно, только для этого надо будет написать целую нетривиальную библиотеку, "задёшево" не получится

Comment: аналогичный вопрос и готовый ответ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1578789/how-do-i-generate-text-matching-a-regular-expression-from-a-regular-expression

Comment: плюс есть готовые онлайн утилиты типа https://www.browserling.com/tools/text-from-regex

Answer (score 1):

Если нужно брать символ из таблицы символов (например, если идут последовательно), то можно использовать функцию [String.fromCharCode](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fromCharCode). Она позволяет по числу вернуть значение символа.
Это лучше, чем использование строки, так как это строка в данном случае не создается.

Касательно регулярных выражений, они используются как раз-таки в тех местах, где нужно получить конкретный результат. Получение произвольного в регулярных выражениях не предусмотрено.

Потому для получения произвольного символа можно использовать либо мой вариант, либо оставить ваш, если он будет проще в реализации.